# Solucion para PHP Notice: Undefined index: internalid

Tags: php, array, indices

No comprendo que pasa mal en este codigo

```
//$expense_categories = explode(chr(13), $row[expense_categories]);
$categoryResult=mysqli_query($db,"SELECT category_id,category FROM expense_categories order by category_id");
if(mysqli_num_rows($categoryResult) > 0){
//echo mysqli_num_rows($categoryResult)."<br/><br/>\n";
    while($catrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($categoryResult)){
        //echo $catrow["internalid"],"  ",$catrow["category"]."<br/>";
        $expense_categories[$catrow["internalid"]]=$catrow["category_id"]; //Linea 14
    }
}
```

Error en log:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: internalid in
>   /var/www/misitio.org/cc/config.inc on line 14, referer:
>   https://misitio.org/cc/

Comment: `internalid`  no está en su consulta `SELECT` por eso no puede acceder a dicho Indice.

Comment: Gracias, desaparecio el error `$expense_categories[$catrow["category_id"]]=$catrow["category_id"];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El Error es simple , no puede acceder al Indice `internalid` dado que no forma parte de su consulta `SELECT` , solo puede acceder a los Indices que llama en su consulta.  O sea `$catrow["category "]`  y `$catrow["category_id"]`